# How to intercept hit data sent to Google Analytics using iOS/Android GTM SDK

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'd like to "clone" the hit data sent to Google Analytics and send it to my own endpoint in a similar way we do it using Tasks in analytics.js

I think it would work like monitoring the tag dispatcher or in a similar way to the custom logging (TAGLogger).

Any custom ideas? Or an "official" way?